# Get Elasticsearch TotalHits from RestHighLevelClient while upgrading from 6.8.X to 7.5.X

Tags: java, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-rest-client

I'm upgrading my Elasticsearch cluster from 6.8.X to 7.5.X. I have [this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/breaking-changes-7.0.html#hits-total-now-object-search-response) breaking change; basically in the REST response, there is a `{hits: {total: { value: 123 } } }` object instead of a `{hits: { total: 123 } }` int value.

Elasticsearch provides an parameter that you can add to your searches `rest_total_hits_as_int`; however, I cannot figure out how to set this on queries being formatted by their java `RestHighLevelClient` or in their `SearchRequest` object. (I'm currently using the ES 6.8.0 libraries.)

When I send a request from the 6.8 client to a 7.5 cluster, I always get `0` total hits. I get an error when I send a request from the 7.5 client to the 6.8 cluster. (Not backwards compatible.)

Is there a migration path that I'm missing?

Comment: can you use the client of 7.5.X ?

Comment: Is the 7.5.X client backwards compatible? It is my understanding that the newer client isn't backwards compatible with an older cluster.

Comment: yeah, newer clients may not be compatible and that's the reason ES releases its client for even its cluster minor version like 7.3, 7.4, 7.5 etc. And you should always use the client version of your cluster

Answer (score 1):

Just add this:

```
searchSourceBuilder.trackTotalHits(true);
```